# Deployed Discord bot (discord.py) to Heroku, turned on the Dyno and bot not responding to commands

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

I've deployed my Discord bot (Discord.py) to Heroku successfully with the build working, I switched on the Dyno and it said the bot has come online and shows as online on Discord's member list on the server. But when I type commands (such as '?help'), the bot doesn't respond at all. Any help would be appreciated, please speak in understandable terms as I'm not the best with too technical language. The token etc. works (and the bot deploys from a private GitHub repo which I know works). I've tried turning on the Dyno then deploying, still no response from the bot.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I've just checked Heroku's logs and it says:

```
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605666+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605667+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605669+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605697+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 822, in process_commands
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605698+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from command.invoke(ctx)
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605700+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 367, in invoke
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605701+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605705+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605704+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 52, in wrapped
2018-04-10T18:04:27.605729+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Embed'`
```

Basically that it has no attribute Embed. Can someone help me fix this please? My requirements.txt is the following:

```
discord.py
websockets
chardet
```

Do I need to add something to my runtime etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This isnt really python related, but are you tagged as an owner of the bot? does the bot have permissions to type in the channel you are requesting it to type in? This is typically something you would ask the owner of the bot/help channel.

Comment: I'm the bot owner, the bot does have permissions to type in the channel also. I ran it locally before and it worked perfectly (via Atom) and responded to me. The bot has admin perms anyway with an administrator role. Still not replying to commands.

Comment: if you run the script in an active session can you see other people typing in the channel? or any output from the session - its hard to say what the issue is without knowing any type of debugging, or what exactly you are working with. (no offense, but its kind of like saying "hey my computers not working, im running windows 7 and i have office installed" it doesn't really give any information.)

Comment: Hey again, what do you mean by active session? Sorry I'm not really familiar with your terminology. This is literally what the Heroku logs say:https://hastebin.com/sovivigena.sql - That is all the Heroku logs say, nothing else. I've tried deploying it multiple times and it still says the same thing.

Comment: Much better - I'm not sure i'll be of any help from here, but it gives you a great starting point for someone with more knowledge on the situation. I guess the first thing is are the packages listed in the requirements installed? (pip install -r requirements.txt/pip3 install -r requirements.txt)

Comment: I've tried using both those commands (pip install -r requirements.txt and pip3) in the Heroku console and they both say requirement already satisfied for my requirements. Here's my requirements file I have now: https://hastebin.com/ovimecaqar.css - am I missing any? Thanks for the help so far Justin.

Comment: In the Procfile it shows: https://hastebin.com/yudiwayiso.http and in the runtime it shows: https://hastebin.com/kodudewima.css

Comment: Sounds like its all done correctly - next i suppose i'd check the version of python the Heroku is running (python -V in the command line) and make sure it aligns with the repo's(github) requirements. did you change anything other then the mentioned above (token, user auth etc) in the configs?

Comment: GitHub Python and Heroku versions are the same. Don't think I've changed the config. It's just the Discord.Embed which is causing the issue, which could be to do with d.py, I'm not too sure. I'll check what Python version d.py can support

Comment: if i had to guess something with your current repo isn't upto date with the current discord.py API. but i could be terribly wrong - you could try joining the discord.py discord and asking around there - its quite active. [discord link](https://discordapp.com/invite/r3sSKJJ) also i should note, discord.py has its OWN requirements, may want to verify those.

Comment: I've joined already and asked, they weren't really much help and said "We're not Heroku support". Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED: After another HOUR of trying many things, I removed my .gitignore and renamed my main.py to run.py. I changed the discord.py version in requirements.txt to what Heroku upgraded it to and re-deployed the bot, and I think upgrading it fixed it, so, job done. I updated the Procfile with the name change from main.py to run.py. Thanks for the help Justin!**